# Using TextJoin with unknown headers

Tags: excel, text, vba

My spreadsheet changes and the number of columns is unknown. The first row of the data contains headers. Using the header values I know are on the sheet, I would like to combine the data into one cell.

Using TextJoin, I would like to create a column with information delimited by spaces

I know this can be done with a formula and now I'm trying to code it in VBA. (Formula solution in the comments)

This is the code I have so far to find and start adding information to the last column:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value = [Formula]
  End With

' Finds the last column
Dim lastColumn As Long
  lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Add Header
Cells(1, lastColumn) = [New Column Header]
```

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

How would the program work on the sample spreadsheet?

Find Columns with the following headers: House Address, Street Name, and Street Type
Find the first available blank column
In the second row, input the following formula: =TextJoin(" ",False,B2,C2,D2)
Fill Formula down the sheet

Since I'm new to VBA, I'm attempting to type formulas into cells versus using coding. This is where I need your help.

Comment: Please post a data sample and explain in context. Why do you need VBA?

Comment: @teylyn I edited the post to include the sample data and how the code would work. I believe i need a vba because the program has to find the columns with predefined headers because the data isn't the same but the headers i'm looking for is the same.

Comment: If you use VBA, why would you want to create a formula to concatenate the address? Why not just write the result into the cell?

Comment: @teylyn this is the only way I knew. How would complete this task with VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

If the three columns you want to concatenate with TextJoin are not in a known position, you can use an Index/Match combo to find the correct column for each value. The Index is on the current row, the Match uses row 1 to find the column label.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,INDEX(A2:G2,MATCH("House Address",$A$1:$G$1,0)),INDEX(A2:G2,MATCH("Street Name",$A$1:$G$1,0)),INDEX(A2:G2,MATCH("Street Type",$A$1:$G$1,0)))
```

With this approach, you can post exactly that formula into row 2 of the first empty column that you find, copy down, and the address will be created by TextJoin.

Comment: Three things. 1. Your formula worked. 2. How would I get this to work as VBA code? 3. In your code, you know the location of the header rows, is there a way to select the header row without knowing this information? Similar to finding the last row or first free column in VBA?

Comment: @ashleedawg This isn't homework. It's work-work. The current response only supplies a formula. An effective formula. I'm researching the other threads to see how to make sense of Index and Match to make my VBA Code. On another note, what school assigns VBA homework? I may be interested in taking one of their classes.

Comment: @AbrahamWalker What is the logic with which you as a human would identify the header row? The last free column is easy, but if the header row is not in a specific row, then there needs to be some logic to determine what row that is. So, what are the rules for that?